# How to push and deploy Reactjs app to gh-pages

Tags: git, reactjs, deployment, github-pages

This is the GitHub repository url - [ProjectManager](https://github.com/ArunaSanjeewa/project_manager_reactjs)
There are no any routes.It includes small components and one API.

I followed these steps now.

1. I switched to the `gh-pages` branch .
2. locally run the `yarn build`command.
3. It already created a **build** folder in my project.

But I need to know how to push it in to gh-pages branch.

Comment: As usual — add, commit, push.

Comment: I try but it commit all files.Not a minified files.

Comment: Then only add files to push. You're not obliged to add everything.

Comment: I found some method.Just checkout below.Thanks

Comment: Check my already made answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339271/committing-documentation-to-a-git-branch-gh-pages/44341936#44341936

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some method to do this

1. Add this to your package.json file

   ```
   "homepage" : "http://<username>.github.io/<reponame>"
   ```
2. Add this script to your package.json file

   ```
    "deploy": "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build"
   ```
3. Install this library .

   ```
    npm install --save-dev gh-pages
   ```
4. After doing these two steps run this command

   ```
   npm run deploy
   ```

It automatically created a branch named `gh-pages` and deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're pointing to your build folder and not your root project folder. You can set this in your github repo settings. One way is to use a separate branch with your build folder as root. Or you can point to the build folder (via settings)